# Adding JScrollPane to my JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, scrollpane

I am having issues getting a vertical scrollbar on my jlist.

listInfo is a vector with data in it.
right panel is a panel on the EAST side of the frame.

If I add just the JList, it appears. If I add scrollpane, nothing happens.

```
        data = new JList(listInfor);
        data.setVisible(true);
        data.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        data.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        data.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(data);
        rightPanel.add(scroll);
```

For some reason, this isn't working.

Comment: Any Exception? Can add some more code please? And how long is `listInfor` ?

Comment: No exceptions, I just can't get my JList to appear.

Comment: listInfo is a vector that takes input from JTextField. I added a ton of names to it and they just didn't appear when names exceeded height of list.

Comment: Had that before posting. Didn't work.

Comment: What's the layout manager of your `rightPanel`? What are its dimensions? Have you tried setting the preferred size on the scroll, instead of the list?

Comment: afsantos, you just inadvertently answered my question. I had no layout, so I changed to BorderLayout and it worked..

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek I'm glad that my comment led you to the answer. I posted it as a community answer, just for the record.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the preferred size of the `JList`, this is preventing it from calculating the size of the list based on it's contents, which will mean that it will never exceed the preferred size you have supplied, meaning that it will never show any scroll bars.

Instead, use a combination of [`JList#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) and [`Jlist#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) to adjust how the `JList` calculates it's preferred size.

IF you REALLY want more control, you should take a look at the [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface that `JList` implements, but even then, I'd be careful

Answer (score 0):

Tested this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            String[] ar = {"one", "two", "three"};
            JList data = new JList(ar);

            data.setVisible(true);
            data.setVisibleRowCount(5);
            data.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
            data.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(data);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("StackOverflow Test");
            frame.add(scroll);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack(); 
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // to center
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

and all it's okay

[image]

Comment: Mine actually still isn't working and I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Ok, now it is. Everything was glitching out. I added BorderLayout() to panel and set preferred dimensions of panel and it showed up

Comment: Do not set the preferred size of the `JList`!  Add 1000 items to the `Jlist`, it will never expand beyond the range of the preferred size you set it to!  This is NEVER the right approach.  If you MUST set the visible range, either use `setVisibleRowCount` and/or `setPrototypeCellValue` which are used by the `getPreferredScrollableSize` to calculate the viewable area initially used by the scroll pane before it will begin scrolling the content...

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a layout manager for your `rightPanel` variable, if it hasn't any. Absence of a layout manager may give you unexpected results, as you don't set the bounds of your components manually.

Besides, as pointed out by [MadProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001337/2088822), you shouldn't set preferred sizes on your components, if possible. There are other ways to determine appealing dimensions. For instance, with `JList`, using `setVisibleRowCount`.

In order for the scroll to appear only as needed, you can specify the scroll bar policies on the `JScrollPane` constructor, or use its *set* methods to do so. Example:

```
jlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jlist);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Also, make sure the container of the scroll pane respects its preferred size, as the scroll pane respects the list's preferred size.

Comment: You're right and it worked. How can I make the scroll only appear when needed? Ie, row count exceeds what I specified?

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek I've addressed your question in the answer. In summary, you should let the JList and its cell renderer calculate the preferred size for the list. The scroll should respect this size (*ie*, try not to set a preferred size on it). If you set the scrollbar policies, it should work as expected.